# how do I place an android project in svn having support libraries

Tags: android, svn

I have already used the svn for the android project and it works well..But my new project have have supporting library projects that i need to include with my current one...how do place the project along with the support libraries to svn. I have placed library manually in the eclipse and placed the project in the svn..but it shows errors in the project...please help me.
Edit:
It doesn't show any error in any java or xml file, but when I try to run it, it says project has errors.

[image: Capture of my work space]

Comment: What sort of errors? Please include more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked the library and android api level dependency?
Edit:
Right click 
project-->properties--->build path-->projects--->remove the existing project -->add new project(slideout activity)

Comment: try removing library and add it in libs folder first then configure the build path.

Comment: I did as you said, but the result is same

Comment: try Project -> clean.
Check warnings and console, what error is displayed there?

Comment: See the screenshot once.....project doesn't have any errors..when I try to run the app it says project have errors...

Comment: yes, I have seen it. but sometimes we miss warnings under Problems view in eclipse, you might get a clue there.
Also try this: Click on your project and click on configure build path, see if you find any error there.

Comment: right click project-->build path-->projects-->remove project--> add new project-->slideout activity, yeah it did the magic thanks @newBee

Comment: I don't have votes today, I will give you upvote tomorrow...cheers